# not able to deploy to heroku - npm start error

Tags: javascript, node.js, heroku, npm-scripts

Trying to deploy an my app to heroku and the build went successfully.  Unfortunately, the Web app did not work.  The error I am getting is to do with the npm start.

```
2018-04-10T16:17:25.752663+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from crashed to   starting
2018-04-10T16:17:27.555672+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Starting process with command   `npm start`
2018-04-10T16:17:29.455213+00:00 heroku[web.1]: State changed from starting to    crashed
2018-04-10T16:17:29.437370+00:00 heroku[web.1]: Process exited with status 1
2018-04-10T16:17:29.378111+00:00 app[web.1]: npm ERR! missing script: start
```

I am assuming that this might have something to do with my package.js folder.  I have put the following in scripts.

```
"scripts": {
"test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1,",
"start": "./index.js"
},
```

When I check if I can run the script locally I get the following error.

```
> rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start /Users/briankaty1/Dropbox/rock-paper-  scissors
> ./index.js

  sh: ./index.js: Permission denied
  npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
  npm ERR! errno 126
  npm ERR! rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start: `./index.js`
  npm ERR! Exit status 126
  npm ERR!
  npm ERR! Failed at the rock-paper-scissors@1.0.0 start script.
  npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional     logging output above.
  npm WARN Local package.json exists, but node_modules missing, did you mean    to install?

 npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
 npm ERR!     /Users/briankaty1/.npm/_logs/2018-04-10T17_33_14_741Z-debug.log
```

I am pretty sure that I have the path to the index.js file is correct.  Ultimately, I want to get this app up and running on heroku.

Comment: Try with `"start": "node index.js"`.

Comment: That seems to work but unfortunately, it still does not work in heroku.

Comment: ``2018-04-10T19:11:43.070028+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/" host=brianp-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com request_id=539defe0-b909-4e89-9fdc-e28548c52137 fwd="94.174.32.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https
2018-04-10T19:11:43.875962+00:00 heroku[router]: at=error code=H10 desc="App crashed" method=GET path="/favicon.ico" host=brianp-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com request_id=ee9441e9-6128-4de7-b035-7f7e02fa4108 fwd="94.174.32.117" dyno= connect= service= status=503 bytes= protocol=https``

Comment: It works locally. I don't know when I deploy it.

Comment: That's a start. Do yo have any missing dependencies in your package.json ?

Comment: I have run ```npm install``` and it now has put the package-lock.json file.  Do you think that would have made the difference?

Comment: It now displays ```Method Not Allowed``` .

Comment: Now I am getting the following error ```GET https://brianpat-rock-paper-scissors.herokuapp.com/favicon.ico 503 (Service Unavailable)```  Any help on getting it deployed to heroku would be appreciated.